# How to output string that is longer than allocated memory

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc

I wrote this code yesterday. My aim is:
I asks user to input a string. I store it in an array. If he inputs a string longer than the array length then after outputting the array characters from array on screen I output rest of the characters with `getchar()` unless I encounter a newline character. The code is here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

#define BACKUP 20

int main()
{
    char *input=NULL;
    char rest[BACKUP],c;

    input= malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    printf("%lu",sizeof(input));

    int i=0,j=1;

    printf("\nEnter a very long string.\n\n>>");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    printf("%s",input);
    while((rest[i]=getchar())!='\n')
    {       
        i=1;    
        for(;i<BACKUP;i++)
            rest[i]=getchar();
        i=0;
        for(;i<BACKUP;i++)
            printf("%c",rest[i]);
        i=0;
    }
return 0;
}
```

The problem is, that first loop goes well but after that it behaves so weird. Can you please correct it.
It would be better if there are other ways to solve this problem.
Can it not be a solution that I output all the character from input area by `getchar()`. I mean, I would not need array in the beginning anymore?
And should I `realloc()` to array and then input rest of the characters in array? And then finally when input area is left with nothing I should print the array content on the screen.
Can anybody tell where the user input is stored meanwhile? And where can I learn/research what happens on the base level under C compiler?

Comment: Why not create an array of such a small length? Perhaps give it a couple of K to play with? Then the problem will not arise in the first place

Comment: One more thing, How can buffer-overflow happen here? I mean I am going to output everything from the "input-area" and so there is no boundations on the user unless memory on hardware level is very low.
Please tell this too, it would enhance my knowledge.

Comment: @SathiyaKumar yes bhai. Can you suggest me what should be that? I would change that.

Comment: You do realize that arrays start counting from 0 and they need to be null terminated for strings?

Comment: @EdHeal What if user is going to input just a character? Then rest of the memory will go in vein, I think. But you are pro so maybe you could tell me what else to do.
Oh yes! I forgot that. Ooops! Mmmmm. . . so I shuld now deal with the last '\n' character. Okay.

Comment: @AshishTomer - Does that matter? Sat in front of a computer with 6GB of memory - so who cares about a K here or there

Comment: @EdHeal ha ha :D
No, I am immature I know but it can be an issue with smart cards or sim cards.
And what is the use of dynamic memory then?
I mean I want to solve it with dynamic memory ( actually I am learning that thing)

Comment: sizeof(pointer) gives you the size of the TYPE of pointer, not of the allocated memory pointed at... [and it also doesn't always output it in bytes!]

Comment: @OlivierDulac can you answer my other questions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
```

is wrong because `sizeof(input)` will give you the size of pointer `input` not the size of allocated memory. Change this to

```
fgets(input, 20, stdin);
```

and to output rest of the characters, try this

```
char rest;
printf("\nEnter a very long string.\n\n>>");
fgets(input, 20, stdin);
printf("%s\n",input);
while((rest=getchar())!='\n')
{
    putchar(rest);
}
```

> Can it not be a solution that I output all the character from input area by `getchar()`. I mean, I would not need array in the beginning anymore?

`getchar` is an input function you can't use it for output. You can do this by using `putchar`. And no need to use an array for the rest of the characters if you want to only output them. I changed `char rest[]` to `char rest`.

> Can anybody tell where the user input is stored meanwhile?

Input get stored in system buffer (shell). When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> key then it goes to the C standard buffer.

Comment: putch() ? okay. I'll use it.
And yes `sizeof(input)` is wrong. I was getting it's size to be 8 and I was curious to know about that problem. Thanks!
Can you answer my rest of the questions please?

Comment: I am on linux so I'll use `putchar()`

Comment: `putchar()` doesn't do it right way. "core dumped" is the error. and gcc also shows some memory map. Can you please help me?

Comment: after edit, I used what you suggested. Though there is no error but a warning is: <br/>
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘putchar’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
And with `printf()` the warning is: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]

Comment: Had you changed `char rest[BACKUP]` to `char rest`?

Comment: He he he It worked! You are cool. But printf() gives warning and putchar() doesn't. So I am using putchar(). 
Thank you :)